# Switching between multiple video tracks in a AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

Is there a way to switch between multiple video tracks in an `AVMutableComposition`? I want to assign a different `preferredTransform` to each, and switch between them.

I tried it by assigning alternating assets to an A track and a B track, but no video showed for the B track time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like to perform the switching between multiple video tracks ("video downmixing") you need to use `AVAssetWriter`. According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the class has "automatic interleaving of media data for multiple concurrent tracks".

So, if you want to preview a composition using multiple video tracks, you either need to write it out using `AVAssetWriter` or compose it in an `AVMutableComposition` using a single video track only.